# ruby * match in string

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I need to detect `*` in string

I try `x =~ /*/` and `x =~ "/*/"`

Both variants are incorrect

Please give me advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` is a quantifier in regular expressions. You need to escape it.

```
s =~ /\*/
```